# Achieve single node field edit to have different values for each user?

Tags: 7, nodes, users, entities

I am trying to create lets say and activity node which allow each user to insert a different value without having to create a node. for example:

I created activity1 node, and then I will allow user a to edit activity1 and insert value "a", and user b can also edit activity1 and insert value "b", and both can see their own activity1(the same node) but with different values for each user.

is this achieveable? as I tried using uniquefields module and that is the one I want for this case.

look forward for some response!

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described it, it is not possible with core Drupal's field system. While you can create a node editable by many users with a multivalue field, the field (and its values) do not have property of ownership. Thus, your requirement to see different values for different users would not work.

There are alternative ways to achieve this. One path is to add 2 fields to the user profile.

- **Activity**: an [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) to your activity node.
- **Value**: the user's field value you want to capture.

If the values are inherent single property of a user, you can add them directly to the user profile and use a [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) to present it as combination of fields for the user to enter.

If the user can have many different **Activity** & **Value** combinations, you could use either use something like [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) or [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck)/[Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) to present an embedded form in the user profile where users can add many different Activity/Value combinations.